Critical Boot Issue: Ubuntu 24.04 Not Loading After apport-autoreport Error - Help!
I'm having serious trouble with my Ubuntu system (running on an HP laptop that originally had Windows installed). After downloading and running an AppImage last night that required FUSE, I installed FUSE, and now my system won't boot properly.

I got into recovery mode through the GRUB menu, and I managed to disable the apport-autoreport service, timer and path, but even after that and updating, upgrading, and updating the distribution, the system still doesn't boot.
I've also seen messages like "No beacon heard, and the time event is over already" and several dependency failures, including sssd-nss.socket.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Disabled apport-autoreport service
Running fsck to check and repair the file system
Updated and upgraded the distribution

None of these steps have resolved the issue, and I'm still stuck. I can't get into the GUI. I'm limited to recovery mode and the terminal.
Edit:
The image below is what the screen displays after I removed the FUSE package and updated the system.


Does it actually stop at the last line shown in the screen shot, the 'thermald` line?

Yes at that moment but it changed after several attempts to solve the problem. Now it is "Started systemd-timedated.service -Time & Date service" and "No beacon heard and the time event is over already". Thanks for your response it is appreciated.  I will add the new image to the write up above

What exactly did you do to "install FUSE"?

This question is similar to: I tried using my system this morning and it's not booting. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@OrganicMarble I installed the FUSE to be able to run a video editor called "OpenShot-v3.2.1-x86_64.AppImage".

@karel thanks for the edit yesterday the questions are for same problem. I created another one because nobody replied to the previous. I will delete the previous one and thanks for the edit.

Exactly what steps did you take to install "fuse"? I use that same appimage and I didn't have to install anything. Since installing "fuse" is what broke your system, we need to know exactly what you did.

It sounds like there is a fix for your issue here https://askubuntu.com/q/1525899/243321

It worked. Thanks soo much I really appreciate it God bless you sir/ma.
