Cannot login to GUI on Ubuntu 24.04 after installing fuse
I recently did an upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04, from 22.04.
I tried to execute an AppImage from National Geographic, but I was not successful.
I installed fuse, following some instructions from other forums, as AppImage Doesn’t Work in Ubuntu? Here’s the Easy Fix.
After that, I rebooted my machine and couldn't login to GUI anymore. Inspecting /var/log/auth.log I noticed these lines:
2024-09-04T08:29:29.375857-04:00 olimpio lightdm: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
2024-09-04T08:29:29.376224-04:00 olimpio lightdm: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
2024-09-04T08:29:29.414461-04:00 olimpio lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "robson"

I thought the problem was concerning .Xauthority permissions, but no luck.

So I followed issue [1516754][2] :
sudo apt purge gdm3
sudo apt install gdm3

and voilà!!! everything goes ok.

Yeah - just went through that myself after installing XNView appimage, which needed fuse.  I've been using Ubuntu since Hardy Heron (8.04 LTS) and I've never seen LTS crap like this and this after waiting until 24.04.1.  I'm going to wait a little longer for 24.04.2 (because I'm a sucker for punishment) before I finally give up and finally try something else - maybe a rolling distro like Arch.  They need to fix this soon before that S in LTS gets derision.

I had the same issue and used Redbob's answer to fix it, but a bit later I realized Nautilus (files manager for Gnome) was gone. I fixed it with: sudo apt install --reinstall nautilus

Please click the check beside your answer to mark it as accepted.
